# Meaning of '&' in C (here in linux kernel function-like Macros)

Tags: c

```
#define TCP_SKB_CB( __skb )   ((struct tcp_skb_cb *)&((__skb)->cb[0]))
```

What does the `&` mean in this context?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's the standard C "address of" operator... The construction above means:

1. `__skb`: the parameter given to the macro (a pointer to a [`struct skbuff`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/skbuff.h?v4.0#L513))
2. `(__skb)->cb`: the `cb` array in the skb
3. `(__skb)->cb[0]`: the first element in the array
4. `&((__skb)->cb[0])`: the address of the first element
5. `((struct tcp_skb_cb *)&((__skb)->cb[0]))`: the address of the first element, cast to a pointer to a `struct tcp_skb_cb`